Dataset of early termination of insurance contracts
I need a dataset of early terminations of insurance contracts in order to predict whether the contract will be terminated or not
It should preferably contain the following features or some of them, but datasets with other attributes will also be useful, BUT there is one very important feature that should be (it is the very last one in the list):
-Age of the policyholder
-Marital status
-Work/Occupation
-Income level
-Education level
-City/Region of residence of the policyholder
-Name of the insurance product (what are we insuring? - a house, a car, ...)
-Total insurance premium under the contract (or in simple terms, the cost of the contract)
-Payment status under the contract (Paid/not paid/partially paid)
-Date of conclusion of the insurance contract
-Date of end of liability under the contract
-Termination status of the contract (whether it was terminated or not) - very important
I have previously found similar datasets, but they mostly came across without the last one the key, most important feature - whether there was a fact of termination or not.
It is desirable that the data be in csv format, you can also specify a link to some open data source that contains the necessary data.
Thanks in advance for any help!

http://dutangc.free.fr/pub/RRepos/pub/web/CASdatasets-manual.pdf

@Nick why not submit that as an answer?

One can look at dutangc.free.fr/pub/RRepos/pub/web/CASdatasets-manual.pdf.
Some datasets can be relevant to your request, for example,

beMTPL16, Belgian motor third-part liability dataset
beMTPL97, a Belgian motor third-part liability dataset
euMTPL, European motor TPL
insurance
freMPL, French Motor Personal Line datasets
ausprivauto, Automobile claim datasets in Australia

